# IndexError: list assignment index out of range in Python while performing TFIDF

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining, tf-idf, indexoutofrangeexception

I was trying to rewrite the TFIDF functions (for my own use) when I seemed to chance upon this IndexError mentioned in the title. Now, I read up a bit on this, but still can't get the meaning properly - this seems to imply that an element with this index does not exist, which does not seem to be the case (as far as I can see). Will greatly appreciate some help on this silly error of mine.
Thanks for helping out.

Code is as follows -

```
tfidf_matrix = [[0 for x in range(len(txt2))] for j in set(nltk.word_tokenize(full1))]

def search1(vocab1,searchFor):
    m=0
    for word,indexNo in vocab1.items():
        if word==str(searchFor):
            m=indexNo
            break
        else:
            m=len(vocab1)+10
    return m

j=0
for idx in range(len(txt2)):
    post = txt2[idx]
    tfidf_matrix[idx] = []
    for term in set(nltk.word_tokenize(post)):
        k = search1(vocab,str(term))
        if k<len(vocab):
            tfidf_matrix[k][idx] = tfidf(term,post,txt2)
        else:
           vocab[str(term)]= j
           tfidf_matrix[j][idx] = tfidf(term,post,txt2)
           j=j+1
```

txt2 is my corpus. It has 2415 documents in it.
full1 is the concatenated version of txt1 i.e. all the strings of txt1 concatenated so that I know before hand how many columns to make the tfidf matrix.

The traceback is as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-5cb754d2e391>", line 23, in <module>
    tfidf_matrix[j][idx] = tfidf(term,post,txt2)

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The exception will tell you what line the error is one, can you include that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Vector57

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in the single code -

```
tfidf_matrix[idx] = []
```

Removed this and it worked beautifully.